# Bash - SUID Program's Child Process did not inherit Parent Process UID as EUID

Tags: linux, penetration-test, buffer-overflow, bash

**Background**

In practicing pentesting a VM on Vulnhub I encountered an issue that is quite interesting with [Brainpan](http://www.vulnhub.com/entry/brainpan-1,51/). After initial access with a limited shell generated from a BoF exploit on a service running on port 9999, I did some basic enumeration and found the following :

1. `sudo -l` revealed that the current shell user (puck) can run a program `anansi_util` owned by another user (anansi) as root, a simple `ls -l <program>` found that I only have executable and read perm on that file, and not write perm.
2. `find / -perm -4000 -type f` revealed another program `validate` within the `/usr/local/bin` directory owned by the other user (anansi), and this program has the SUID bit set.
   *(which should mean the program's forked child processes should inherit the parent program's uid as euid)* puck also has read and executable perm on validate.

So I decided to explore finding #2 and try to exploit the SUID set program with another BoF. The shellcode I generated was from msfvenom and it was a `linux/x86/exec` payload and option `CMD=bash`. I was able to exec another `bash` prompt after successfully exploiting the BoF issue the program had.

**Issue**

The `bash` program forked from `validate` did not give itself the euid of anansi, who owns the program/file `validate` inside the `usr/bin/local` directory , and the process still belonged to puck with no euid when I execute `id`

**Question**

Is this expected behavior? I always thought that if we fork a process from a parent process who's SUID bit is set, that the child process will inherit the parent process's uid as euid, isn't that what `sudo` does?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you, I didn’t see the link until now. Basically it says that bash like other shells will drop priv during start up. I will try to get a python interpreter instead and have that spawn bash, see if that’ll work as a workaround.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich invoking /bin/sh would work in this VM.

Comment: @Rennitbaby you may be able to try `/bin/sh -p` to retain the EUID of the file's owner.